# Lee Algorithm for Medial Axis Transformation

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

Anybody knows an implementation of the [Lee algorithm](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Spring16/Lee82.pdf) for Medial Axis Transformation or just a pseudocode of it to understand? Language doesn't matter, I just need to fully understand how it works. The input is any polygon given the vertex in 2D and the output is the MAT tree. I saw some articles about the algorithm, but they were not clear enough.

Comment: Check out this page: https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Spring16/Lee82.pdf

Comment: already seen that